# Same QR code for two different app stores

Tags: app-store, user-agent, qr-code

I have been thinking about making a QR code that goes to a webpage which then queries the user agent ID and redirects to the correct app store depending on the mobile telephone. (Google Play and iTunes) Would detecting the user agent be a sufficient solution to this? Or do I need to consider other/more data? (I am thinking best thing would be e.g. a PHP code library hosted on own domain, but alternatively and online service.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Sniffing the user-agent is the best way to determine which phone is which.

Do note, that some users will have switched from their phone's default browser to a 3rd party one such as Chrome, Firefox, Dolphin, etc.

Generally, checking the presence of "Android" in the User-Agent string is enough.

In PHP, you can use http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

```
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if (stripos($ua, "android") !== FALSE) {
     // Send to Play Store
}
```

Make sure that if you don't recognise the UA, you give the user a choice of where to go - Play Store, App Store, your homepage, etc.

Finally, make sure you keep accurate statistics.  If you see lots of BlackBerry users scanning your code - it's time to make a BlackBerry App :-)